# How to set up media player like WhatsApp voice notes (recyclerview)?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

What I'm trying to do is something like the image below. voices notes inside a `recyclerView` using `MediaPlayer`.

[image]

Audio should play when the play button is pressed and when the audio ends set the seek bar to 0 and stop the player.

The application should also avoid playing audio simultaneously if an audio note is playing and the user tries to play a new one.how can I do something like that? should I create a `MediaPlayer` every time the user clicks on the play button or always use the same player?

Comment: I Think Blow Link Help You:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69024917/media-player-in-recyclerview-play-at-the-same/69083122#69083122](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69024917/media-player-in-recyclerview-play-at-the-same/69083122#69083122)

Comment: @Mike-OS Did you got a solution for this