# media player in recyclerview play at the same

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

I'm using media player in recycler view and the problem is when  different item's play buttons are clicked they all play at the same time. How can I stop the previous one and start the new one?

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        final   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(item.get(position).getAudio());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

viewHolder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        viewHolder.play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    viewHolder.play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my `recyclerView` adapter and you must put your arraylist in this adapter

```
public class MyAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter2.AudioItemsViewHolder> {

static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Activity activity;


private final ArrayList<GroupItems> audioItems;//change it() to your items
private int currentPlayingPosition;
private final SeekBarUpdater seekBarUpdater;
private AudioItemsViewHolder playingHolder;



   public MyAdapter2(Activity activity, ArrayList<GroupItems> items_pro) {
    this.audioItems = items_pro;
    this.currentPlayingPosition = -1;
    seekBarUpdater = new SeekBarUpdater();
    this.activity = activity;

}    


@Override
public AudioItemsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  //put YourItemsLayout;
    return new AudioItemsViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(YourItemsLayout, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AudioItemsViewHolder holder, int position) {
if (position == currentPlayingPosition) {
        playingHolder = holder;
        updatePlayingView();
    } else {
        updateNonPlayingView(holder);
    }
}
   private void updateNonPlayingView(AudioItemsViewHolder holder) {
    holder.sbProgress.removeCallbacks(seekBarUpdater);
    holder.sbProgress.setEnabled(false);
    holder.sbProgress.setProgress(0);
    holder.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_arrow_24);
}

private void updatePlayingView() {
    playingHolder.sbProgress.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    playingHolder.sbProgress.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    playingHolder.sbProgress.setEnabled(true);
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        playingHolder.sbProgress.postDelayed(seekBarUpdater, 100);
        playingHolder.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
    } else {
        playingHolder.sbProgress.removeCallbacks(seekBarUpdater);
        playingHolder.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_arrow_24);
    }
}
  private class SeekBarUpdater implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (null != playingHolder && null != mediaPlayer) {
            playingHolder.sbProgress.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            playingHolder.sbProgress.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return audioItems.size();
}
 
    class AudioItemsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    SeekBar sbProgress;
    ImageView ivPlayPause;
    AudioItemsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
     ivPlayPause = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sound_btn);
        ivPlayPause.setOnClickListener(this);
        sbProgress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        sbProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.seekBar:
                break;

            case R.id.sound_btn: {
                if (getAdapterPosition() == currentPlayingPosition) {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                    } else {
                        if (mediaPlayer != null)
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                } else {
                    currentPlayingPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        if (null != playingHolder) {
                            updateNonPlayingView(playingHolder);
                        }
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                    }
                    playingHolder = this;



                   
                        PlaySound(YOUR AUDIO FILE);//put your audio file


                }
                if (mediaPlayer != null)
                    updatePlayingView();
            }
            break;
    }


    }


     @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }
}
 private void PlaySound(File filesound) {

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(activity, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(filesound)));

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (null != playingHolder) {
        updateNonPlayingView(playingHolder);
    }
    if (outputFile.exists())
        outputFile.delete();

    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;
    currentPlayingPosition = -1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do

1. Use a single global `MediaPlayer` rather than a player per view. Then when you click an item, stop the audio, set a new data source, and restart i.e. don't create a new `MediaPlayer` instance everytime in `onBindViewHolder`

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); // Somewhere at the top of your code
```

Now you can use the `mediaPlayer` directly anywhere and don't assign a new instance to this

2.If for some reason you need to do it like so,

You first have to check if there is a sound that is already playing and if there is, you should stop it when the user decides to start a new sound.

```
viewholder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaplayer.isPlaying ()) {
                    if (mediaplayer != null){
                        mediaplayer.stop ();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mediaplayer != null) {
                        mediaplayer.start ();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

In setOnCompletionListner you release the sound if the user listens to the whole sound clip.

```
mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListner (new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListner () {
            public void OnCompletion (MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
                mediaplayer.release ();
            }
        });
```

I will personally recommend the first solution as your application will take much lesser memory in that case

Comment: the second solution doesn't work for me and I didn't completely understand your first solution. can you write some code for that please? @gtxtreme

Comment: I did as you said and then put the try catch inside play button's else. and I faced error for setDataSource line